# Why is code throwing renderer error in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, renderer

Rather peculiar. The code had been working prior and I left it running. When I returned, the sphere was no longer being rendered onto the webpage.

I added three light objects and GUI sliders to them to vary their position and light intensities in GUI folders and that's about when the code stopped working.

The following errors were thrown:
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context.
Uncaught Error: Error creating WebGL context.
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'renderer' before initialization.

```
// Loader
const textureLoader = new TextureLoader()
const normalTexture = textureLoader.load('/textures/Sphere-map.jpg')

// Debug
const gui = new dat.GUI()

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x7d7d7d); // soft white light
scene.add(light);

// Objects
const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(.5, 64, 64);

// Materials

const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()
material.color = new THREE.Color(0xFF4FA7)
material.metalness = 0.3
material.roughness = 0.8
material.normalMap = normalTexture

// Mesh
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, material)
scene.add(sphere)


// Lights
const light1 = gui.addFolder('Light 1')
const light2 = gui.addFolder('Light 2')
const light3 = gui.addFolder('Light 3')

// light 1
const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFF4FA7, 0.1)
pointLight.position.set(0, 0, 0)
pointLight.intensity = 1
scene.add(pointLight)

light1.add(pointLight.position, 'y').min(-3).max(3).step(0.01)
light1.add(pointLight.position, 'x').min(-6).max(6).step(0.01)
light1.add(pointLight.position, 'z').min(-3).max(3).step(0.01)
light1.add(pointLight, 'intensity').min(0).max(10).step(0.01)


// Light 2
const pointLight2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2)
pointLight2.position.set(0.8, 0.67, 0.8)
pointLight2.intensity = 1
scene.add(pointLight2)

light2.add(pointLight2.position, 'y').min(-3).max(3).step(0.01)
light2.add(pointLight2.position, 'x').min(-6).max(6).step(0.01)
light2.add(pointLight2.position, 'z').min(-3).max(3).step(0.01)
light2.add(pointLight2, 'intensity').min(0).max(10).step(0.01)


// Light 3
const pointLight3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2)
pointLight3.position.set(-1.71, -3, 3)
pointLight3.intensity = 1
scene.add(pointLight3)

light3.add(pointLight3.position, 'y').min(-3).max(3).step(0.01)
light3.add(pointLight3.position, 'x').min(-6).max(6).step(0.01)
light3.add(pointLight3.position, 'z').min(-3).max(3).step(0.01)
light3.add(pointLight3, 'intensity').min(0).max(10).step(0.01)

/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    // Update sizes
    sizes.width = window.innerWidth
    sizes.height = window.innerHeight

    // Update camera
    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

    // Update renderer
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
})

/**
 * Camera
 */
// Base camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.x = 0
camera.position.y = 0
camera.position.z = 2
scene.add(camera)

// Controls
// const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)
// controls.enableDamping = true

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))


/**
 * Animate
 */

const clock = new THREE.Clock()

const tick = () => {

    const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

    // Update objects
    sphere.rotation.y = .5 * elapsedTime

    // Update Orbital Controls
    // controls.update()

    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    // Call tick again on the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick()
```

Comment: Title mentions an error, yet you don't include it in your question?

Comment: According to your error, you are trying to access `renderer` before you initialise it. Try defining your resize listener after your initialisation of `renderer`.

Comment: @Berthur Thank you your solution worked but it's still not rendering

Comment: @ImmortalNoob Any remaining errors?

Comment: @Berthur The following errors: three.module.js:23220 THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context, Uncaught Error: Error creating WebGL context.
    at new WebGLRenderer, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Berthur exclude the last error, just the first two now

Comment: @ImmortalNoob So this happened only after you left it running? Well, have you tried running it again / restarting the machine? See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4927

Comment: @Berthur Thank you, the link you provided was very helpful. Turns out I just needed to update my Chrome

Comment: @ImmortalNoob So it persisted even after a computer restart? That is peculiar indeed :) Glad you got it solved

Answer (score 0):

I update Chrome and now the code works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).